# SAP BO - Time elapsed between first and last day of month (downtime)

Tags: business-objects, elapsedtime, webi

I want to calculate the total downtime of the machines between the first and the last day of the month.

My time measure is Stillstandzeit [h]

I have identified the:

- First day of last month: `=RelativeDate(LastDayOfMonth( RelativeDate([Last day of Last Month];-45));+1)`
- Last day of last month: `=RelativeDate([First day of Current Month];-1)`

And I want to find the hours in between.

Thanks a lot.

Ektor

Comment: Total hours between your two dates would be something like this....

**=DaysBetween([First Day of Previous Month]; [Last Day of Previous Month]) * 24**

Is that what you want?

Comment: Not exactly. 
I want to measure the recorder time (Stillstandzeit [h] ) between these 2 days.